# AuthorizationException when calling Transaction.SubmitForPartialSettlement

Tags: asp.net, braintree

When trying to submit a Transaction for a Partial Settlement, I'm getting the following exception + message:

```
Exception of type 'Braintree.Exceptions.AuthorizationException' was thrown.
```

There is nothing else to explain where I've gone wrong.

This is how I'm making the API call:

```
BraintreeHandler.Gateway.Transaction.SubmitForPartialSettlement(“transaction_id”, amount);
```

I know the Transaction Id is correct, because I'm loading the Transaction information beforehand. I'm also always using an amount less than the transaction total.

```
BraintreeHandler.Gateway.Transaction.SubmitForSettlement(“transaction_id”, amount);
```

The above works fine with an amount, but I don't want to submit the Transaction for settlement as I'd like to retain the ability to partially settle.

**For example:** If I have a Transaction Amount of £50 with a status of "Authorized", I'd like to be able to settle for £20, £20 and £10 on three separate occasions. With the `SubmitForSettlement()` method I can only settle for the initial £20 before the status is updated to "Submitted for Settlement". After this I can't perform any more partial settlements.

Information pertaining to the `SubmitForPartialSettlement()` method is conspicuously missing from the [Transaction](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/transaction/dotnet) docs on the Braintree developer site. Has the method been deprecated? If not, how can I make use of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

`SubmitForPartialSettlement` is a feature currently being tested and is not available to all merchants at this time. If you would like to request multiple partial settlements to be enabled for your account, please reach out to [Braintree support](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/) or your account manager.

For the time being, you have the correct solution in `SubmitForSettlement`, passing in an `amount` less than or equal to the transaction amount. You will only be able to settle once.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would you be able to give a rough time estimate as to when the partial settlement functionality will be available? Braintree is a no go for us if we don't have this functionality. I'm currently testing in the sandbox environment.